# Proof concerning matrix norm.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am struggling with following proof, could you give me some hint or some information which would help me in proving following inequality?

$$\|AB\|_{\infty} \le \|A\|_\infty\|B\|_\infty$$
for every $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $\|A\|_\infty = \max_i \sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}| =$ maximum absolute row sum.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
$$
\|AB\| = \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|ABx\| \leq \max_{\|x\| = 1} \|A\| \|Bx\| \leq \|A\| \|B\|
$$

Comment: Thank you for hint, but I cannot manage to understand why ∥AB∥=max∥ABx∥, where ||x||=1

Comment: That's the definition of an operator norm (aka "induced norm").  You should be able to find that as the definition of $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ somewhere in your text.